# Batch Statements vs Multiple Value Inserts

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

JDBC has a feature of group multiple queries in one single unit and pass it in a single network trip to the database.

As shown in this code example:

```
String[] EMPLOYEES = new String[]{"Zuck","Mike","Larry","Musk","Steve"};
String[] DESIGNATIONS = new String[]{"CFO","CSO","CTO","CEO","CMO"};

String insertEmployeeSQL = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(ID, NAME, DESIGNATION) VALUES (?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement employeeStmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertEmployeeSQL);

for(int i = 0; i < EMPLOYEES.length; i++){
    String employeeId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    employeeStmt.setString(1,employeeId);
    employeeStmt.setString(2,EMPLOYEES[i]);
    employeeStmt.setString(3,DESIGNATIONS[i]);
    employeeStmt.addBatch();
}
employeeStmt.executeBatch();
```

But, with SQL we have the feature of using INSERTs with many VALUES groups, just like at:

```
String[] EMPLOYEES = new String[] {"Zuck","Mike","Larry","Musk","Steve"};
String[] DESIGNATIONS = new String[] {"CFO","CSO","CTO","CEO","CMO"};

StringBuilder insertEmployeeSQL = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(ID, NAME, DESIGNATION) VALUES (?,?,?)"
    + ", (?, ?, ?)".repeat(EMPLOYEES.length - 1);

PreparedStatement employeeStmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertEmployeeSQL.toString());

int columnIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < EMPLOYEES.length; i++){
    String employeeId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    employeeStmt.setString(++columnIndex, employeeId);
    employeeStmt.setString(++columnIndex, EMPLOYEES[i]);
    employeeStmt.setString(++columnIndex, DESIGNATIONS[i]);
}

employeeStmt.execute();
```

What I need to know is, what is the difference between these two approaches?

Obs:

The first example is from here https://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-batch-processing and the second edited by me.
English is not my native language and this is my first post so sorry for anything.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` with multiple `VALUES` blocks, i.e. multiple `(val, ...)` blocks is not valid SQL syntax. Oh sure, *some* databases might support that *extended* syntax, but not all of them do.

Even if *your* database does, using that syntax will greatly increase the number of statement parameters, and all of the databases have a limit to the number of parameter is allowed in a single request. The actual limit varies by database. Batching doesn't have a batch size limit, other than amount of memory for storing all the values.

Comment: Insert with multiple values is definitely valid SQL syntax, it is defined in ISO-9075-2:2016 (the SQL standard), specifically in 14.11 <insert statement> combined with 7.3 <table value constructor>. It is just that some database systems don't support the table value constructor (the values clause) as such, and only support a simpler 'single row' variant of the values clause.